# Tkinter in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tkinter

I'm creating a game in Python using Tkinter and wanted to use Google App Engine to put my game online.

I just want the link randomappname.appspot.com to go directly to my game, nothing fancy or anything. I never used GAE before, so I was wondering what is the simplest way to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: GAE is for hosting web applications. Tkinter is for creating desktop GUI applications. How are you hoping it will work online?

Comment: I don't know how it would work online...I was hoping there was a way for GAE to do that, but since it doesn't support Tkinter I don't know what to use anymore. Is there some other way to get my game online?

Comment: It's not a question of GAE "supporting Tkinter". Web apps and desktop apps are fundamentally different: to make an app work on the web, you need to get it to accept HTTP requests and output HTML. Tkinter just doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is not designed to run in a browser. It was possible at one time to run Tk in a browser by using a [tcl plugin](http://www.tcl.tk/software/plugin/download.html), but I doubt that plugin works with any modern browsers (the current release is dated 2006), and it won't work with Tkinter since Tkinter depends on python.